# Why following Java code won't update a Solr document?

Tags: java, solr

I have a Solr collection (smartDocument with multiple fields like id, path, name, type etc) and I want to update a specific field, called ai_finished. I first retrieve the smartDocument, then *accordingly* populate a SolrInputDocument, change the field with false value, and then commit the changes.

The result? If I query Solr, it changes the ai_finished for a second or so, and then it reverts back to the old value. Why does it do this?

Here's the code that I've tried in Java:

```java
SolrConfigIndependently solrConfigIndependently = new SolrConfigIndependently();
HttpSolrClient solrClient = solrConfigIndependently.solrHttpClient(solrURL, coreName);

SolrInputDocument document = new SolrInputDocument();
document.addField("id", documentId);

try {
    SmartDocument sd = this.searchDocById(documentId, coreName);

    document = SolrInputDocumentMapper.createSolrDocumentFromSmartBox(sd);
    Map<String,String> AI_FINISHED= new HashMap<>();
    AI_FINISHED.put("set", "false");
    document.setField(SmartDocumentEnum.AI_FINISHED.getValue(),AI_FINISHED);

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// Update the smartDocument
try {
    solrClient.add(document);
    solrClient.commit();
} catch (SolrServerException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// Close the Solr client
try {
    solrClient.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

What do I have to do to actually commit the changes?

Comment: Have you looked at the Solr request log to verify that there isn't a second request coming right after that changes the value back? Have you tried attaching a breakpoint at the `commit` command and seeing what values it's reporting?

Comment: Right at the .add command the value it's the correct one(false), it's after the commit that it reverts to the old value(ironically, because commit should persist the changes)

Comment: But you're seeing the correct value for a second if you're querying the document directly from Solr's Admin interface?

Comment: Yes, then after the commit it reverts back to true